# Unable to set 'int' in CoreData as NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsnumber

I have an attribute that is described as Int16.  It is described in the .h file as NSNumber.  No matter how I format it, I can't seem to get the valid value of either 12 or 24 stored in UserDefaults.  What am I doing wrong?  or, better yet, how do I fix this so *aHourFormat* is the same as *timeFormat*?

This is the code:

```
updateData.aHourFormat = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[preferencesDict objectForKey:@"timeFormat"]];
NSLog(@"\ntimeFormat: %d\naHourFormat: %d",[[preferencesDict objectForKey:@"timeFormat"]intValue],[updateData.aHourFormat intValue]);
```

This what NSLog displays in the debug console:

> ```
> timeFormat: 12
> aHourFormat: -30496
> ```

and

> ```
> timeFormat: 24
> aHourFormat: 14000
> ```

This is the definition of *aHourFormat*:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *aHourFormat;
```

Comment: `Int16` is `short`, `Int32` is `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
updateData.aHourFormat = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[preferencesDict objectForKey:@"timeFormat"]];
```

To:

```
updateData.aHourFormat = [preferencesDict objectForKey:@"timeFormat"];
```

`objectForKey:` returns an object. If you cast it to an `NSInteger` then you'll get a value related to its address; if you then pack that into an `NSNumber` then that's what you'll get when you later unpack as `intValue`.

You just want the object directly.

You'll otherwise be getting a reliable result because of a thing called [tagged pointers](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html), which relates to the way that memory addresses can be used so that there's not really anything in memory on 64-bit platforms. It's not worth worrying about other than to be aware that the dependable result isn't surprising.

Comment: I changed the code and it worked once!  the data in PreferencesDict is valid, but when I try to update *aHourFormat*, it's zero (0).  any ideas?

Comment: Let it sleep overnight, and viola!  it's working all the time now... who knows why!  :D
Thanks again...